# Expose Services to local environment for production

Tags: database, swisscomdev

I am planning to move different service to Swisscom Application Cloud, but I have a problem on database access.

My setup is a web application and a local service sharing the same database, unfortunately the local service can't be moved to the cloud at the moment, there is a way for my local service to access the database in the cloud?

I think using the service connector in production is not a good idea

I know the best solution would be to avoid direct access to the database from the local service and expose REST API from the web application but that's out of budget

Answer (score 7):

You are right: External service access to database services running in the cloud is not possible and the service connector is not suitable for permanent use.

This is by design: The services in the marketplace are meant to be used by the apps running there - the apps themselves should expose their functionality over HTTPS preferably. We'd like to avoid allowing external access to the databases; this would open the door for a lot of external (legacy) apps with a complete different set of requirements.

So the solution that fits the architecture best is indeed your suggestion: Expose the data needed for the legacy service as part of the apps' Web API.

Since that is out of question, it might make sense to host the database outside of the cloud (i.e. where the local service runs or on some 3rd party provider) and connect your app in the cloud to this externally running database.